# Print the first letter of each word of a sentence

Tags: java, string

I need to extract the first character from each word present in the sentence.
the output should be : JaJwuth but it coming : JJJJJaaaaJJJJJwwwwwuuutttthhhhh

**Here is my code:**

```
class new_word {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = "Jack and Jill went up the hill";
        s = ' ' + s; /* adding space before the string */
        char ch;
        int i, l;
        l = s.length();
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == (' '))
                ch = s.charAt(i + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(ch); /* here the error appears */
    }
}
```

Please help me understand what I did wrongly, thanks.the output should be:JaJwuth

Comment: The error message is clear. The Java compiler does not check your loop conditions and cannot infer that `l` is the length of a more than `1` length string. It also does not check that it does contains `' '`. So initialize your `ch` like this: `char ch = s.charAt(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize `ch`

change

```
char ch;
```

to

```
char ch=' ' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than the initialization problem that you are getting for `char ch;`, which you fix by initializing it with an empty char (`char ch = ' ';`), this is probably what you are trying to do (without using char ch):

```
class new_word {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = "Jack and Jill went up the hill";
        s = ' ' + s; /* adding space before the string */
        int strLen = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == (' '))
                System.out.println(s.charAt(i + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
J
a
J
w
u
t
h
```

Note: The `System.out.println(...)` was outside the for loop in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to intialize `ch` because in the instance the for loop isn't run (for example when i >=1) then ch will never be initialized and then you're trying to print out a variable that isn't initialized

```
char ch ='\0';
```

Comment: `''` is not a valid character.

Comment: My apologies.  Fixed it!